# TypeError: Cannot read property 'characters' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have added a method which I want to use on a button.I am trying to delete a field from the table but getting an error. I had initially declared the state with an array.I assume that this error is being generated while setting the state with the filtered array. I am not sure what's wrong here.

Error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'characters' of undefined`
[image]
App.js:

```
import Table from './Table';
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  state={
    characters : [
      {
        name: 'Smit',
        job: 'Theme Specialist',
      },
      {
        name: 'Charlie',
        job: 'Janitor',
      },
      {
        name: 'Mac',
        job: 'Bouncer',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dee',
        job: 'Aspring actress',
      },
      {
        name: 'Dennis',
        job: 'Bartender',
      },
    ]
  }

  removeElement(index){

    this.setState({
     characters: this.state.characters.filter(i=>{
        return i !== index
      })

    })
    console.log("remove"+this.state.characters)
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
           <Table data={this.state.characters} deleted={this.removeElement}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Table.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'




function TableHeader() {
    return (
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Job</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    )
}

function TableBody(props) {

       const dataBody= props.data.map( (index)=>{

               return(

                    <tr key={index.data}>

                        <td>
                         {index.name}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                         {index.job}
                        </td>
                        <button onClick={()=>
                            props.deleted(index)
                        }>
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </tr>

               )
           })
    return(
        <tbody>
            {dataBody}
        </tbody>
    ) 


}

export default class Table extends Component {
    render() {


        return (

    <table>
       <TableHeader/>
       <TableBody data={this.props.data} deleted={this.props.deleted}/>

      </table>

        )
    }
```

}

Comment: Make sure your app setup supports 'class field declarations' syntax if you want to initialise state this way: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-without-constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a typical react `this` pitfall. When you pass a method of parent class to child components as prop, most of the time, you want its `this` bound.

```
<Table
    data={this.state.characters}
    deleted={this.removeElement.bind(this)}
/>
```

Better, you can use arrow function syntax to declare the method in the first place, so you don’t need to worry about the `this` problem later on.

```
removeElement = (index) => { ... }
```

Now `.bind(this)` is no longer necessary.

Comment: If you are going to use bind it is better to do it in a constructor if you are using a class so that it doesn't bind a new method every render: `this.removeElement = this.removeElement.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1):

use arrow function as class method:

```
removeElement = (index)=>{

    this.setState({
     characters: this.state.characters.filter(i=>{
        return i !== index
      })

    })
    console.log("remove"+this.state.characters)
  }
```